# WSO2 ESB warning, SystemValidator Could not validate the system for configuration parameter : CPU

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In my ESB service (v 4.6.0) error log file (wso2-esb-errors.log), have the warning:
**SystemValidator Could not validate the system for configuration parameter : CPU**

What is it meaning ? And how can I fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be happened due to your configuration. You can find the recommended system configuration values which are specified in ESB_HOME/repository/conf/etc/config-validation.xml file.

```
<Validator class="org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator"> 
<Parameter id="CPU">1024</Parameter> 
<Parameter id="RAM">2048</Parameter> 
<Parameter id="swap">256</Parameter> 
<Parameter id="freeDisk">1024</Parameter> 
<Parameter id="ulimit">1000</Parameter> 
</Validator>
```

Are using the IBM JDK?. If so the reason could be the one reported at[1].

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14125

Comment: Thanks,
A. I was not change the configuration of config-validation.xml B. I am using Oracle JDK 1.6 update 25.

Answer (score 0):

During SystemValidator phase what actually happens is Carbon server check the configuration of the running system with the recommended settings on ESB_HOME/repository/conf/etc/config-validation.xml.
Since you haven't change the config file according to your case server has failed to validate CPU performance. Possible situation can be your CPU performance is below the recommended value(1024 MHz). As a fix you may need to run your ESB server on machine with recommended settings.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Manoj,
thanks your response.

in ESB_HOME/repository/conf/etc/config-validation.xml, the configuration value as below:
<Validator class="org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator">
                <Parameter id="CPU">2000</Parameter>
                <Parameter id="RAM">2048</Parameter>
                <Parameter id="swap">4000</Parameter>
                <Parameter id="freeDisk">1024</Parameter>
                <Parameter id="ulimit">4096</Parameter>
        </Validator>

and, cat /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz  : 2394.036

2394.036 > 2000

Comment: Hi Gordon, Yes this should work according to your cpu configuration. Its hard to predict what cause the problem. I observed the config-validation.xml file on ESB 4.6.0 the original value was <Parameter id="CPU">800</Parameter> in that. I think as a work-around you can modified it to default value. During operation you will not cause any problems since your configurations are more than enough on recommended settings. Hope my comment helps you :)